# Getting uncaught issue: Too few argument to function in getKYCByUserID() in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

i am using CodeIgniter Web Framework to build my web application and i am getting below error. i am stuck in this and no idea how to fix it. i am new in CodeIgniter. please help me thanks in advance.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\application\helpers\basic_helper.php:16 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\application\views\default\welcome\index.php(1): getKYCByUserID(1) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\system\core\Loader.php(833): include('D:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\system\core\Loader.php(419): CI_Loader->_ci_load(Array) #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\application\controllers\welcome.php(14): CI_Loader->view('default/welcome...') #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): Welcome->index() #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\index.php(206): require_once('D:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\application\helpers\basic_helper.php on line 16

```
 function getKYCByUserID($user_id){                 
    $this->db->where('id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');
    return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you called `getKYCByUserID($user_id)` but you didn't call it with a parameter. So this is not the code that is causing the issue its where you call this method where the error is

Comment: Okay, let me try

Answer (score 0):

You should get instance of ci and load database in helper and also call function with parameter. try the following function

```
function getKYCByUserID($user_id){      
    $inst =& get_instance();
    $inst->load->database();                
    $inst->db->where('id', $user_id);
    $query = $inst->db->get('tbl_users');
    return $query->row();
}
```